# default icons provided in wp7 sdk how we can use them

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to use icons provided in wp7 sdk, my doubt is do i need to copy the required icon to my image folder or I can use them without copying. Please help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to include them into your project.

If you add them through the solution explorer in Visual Studio, it will copy it to the local location for you.

Don't forget to change the Build Action to "Content"!

Answer (score 4):

Just as a little extra, this is the location for if you don't know this:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons

Could also be 'Program Files (x86)' depending on your system and in the folder Icons choose 'dark' or 'light'.